# Calculate the sum of individual categories in microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to work on a Accounting finance sheet for budgeting. I am stuck here. I want to calculate the sum of individual categories in "Actual Expenses" column. For example - The sum of "Fixed Expenses" from the range B15:B19 has to be in I3 cell. The sum of "Travel" category from the range B15:B19 has to be in the I4 cell. Could anyone help me out with the formula here?

[image]

Comment: I can try with pivot table but need to know whether any other way is possible or not :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SUMIF` function. On cell J3, enter the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($B$15:$B$19,"=" & I2,$C$15:$C$19)
```

Drag the formula down to fill the other cells.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this also:*

- Formula in cell J3:

  =SUMPRODUCT(--($B$15:$B$19=$I3),$C$15:$C$19)
- Adjust the cell references as needed.